# React Native Scrollview is not scrolling down

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-scrollview

i gave been trying  to create a scrollable screen every thing looks fine however the screen is not scrolling for some reason i'm not sure what's the problem this is my first time working with react native and all the diffrent components are bugging me. This is my code i'll be removing some extra code like the imports, logic and the fetch request cause it's too long:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { 
  View, 
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
SafeAreaView} from 'react-native'

let {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
let {height} = Dimensions.get('window');

const PriceComparison = ( { route, navigation: { goBack } } ) => {
const {onAdd} = useStateContext();
const {itemId, itemName, itemStore, itemCategory} = route.params;
const [data, setData] = useState();
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height

return (
<SafeAreaView style={
    { 
        flex: 1,
        
       }
}>

{isLoading ? (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1,  width: width, height: height}} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
        <Text>Loading....</Text>
    </ScrollView>
    ) : (
        <View style={{height: screenHeight, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <View style={{height: '100%'}}>
                    <View style={styles.Header}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.button}
                            onPress={() => goBack()}
                        >
                            <Icon icon ='arrow-back-outline' color='#000'/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={{fontWeight: '800', fontSize: 20}}>Price Comparison</Text>

                    </View >
                    { (dataLength !== 0) ?
                        <View style={{height: '100%'}}>
                            {data?.sort((a,b) => {return a.price-b.price}).slice(0, 1).map((product) => (
                                <View style={{height: '50%'}}>
                                    <View style={{height: '100%'}}>
                                        {dummyData.storesData.filter((img) => img.store ===  product.store ).map((img) => (
                                            <View style={styles.Cheapest}>
                                                <View style={styles.CheapestLogo}>
                                                    <Image 
                                                        style={styles.CheapestLogoImage} 
                                                        source={{ uri: `${img.shopbyimg}` }}
                                                    />
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={styles.CheapestDetails}>
                                                    <Image 
                                                        style={styles.ProductImage} 
                                                        source={{ uri: `${product.image}` }}
                                                    />
                                                        <View style={styles.CheapestTitle}>
                                                            <View style={{width: '70%'}}>
                                                                <Text style={styles.CheapestName}> {product.name} <Text style={styles.CheapestMeasurement}> {product.measurement} </Text></Text>
                                                            </View>
                                                            <Text style={styles.CheapestPrice}> ${product.price}</Text>
                                                        </View>
                                                        <View style={styles.CheapestSavings}>
                                                            <Text style={styles.SavePrice}> Save: ${saving} </Text>
                                                            <Text style={styles.SavePercentage}> Save up to {percentageSaving}% </Text>
                                                        </View>   
                                                        <TouchableOpacity 
                                                            style={{backgroundColor: COLORS.primary, padding: 15, borderRadius: 4, width: '92%', marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto'}}
                                                            onPress={() => {onAdd(product, qty)}}
                                                        >
                                                            <Text 
                                                                style={{
                                                                    color: '#fff', 
                                                                    fontWeight: '600', 
                                                                    textAlign: 'center'
                                                                }}>
                                                                ADD TO CART
                                                            </Text>
                                                        </TouchableOpacity>                             
                                                </View>
                                            </View>
                                        ))} 
                                    </View>
                                    
                                </View>
                            ))}    
                            {data?.sort((a,b) => {return a.price-b.price}).slice(1, data.length).map((product) => (
                                <View 
                                    style={{
                                        height: '50%', 
                                        marginTop: 80, 
                                        backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
                                        marginTop: 100, 
                                        width: '92%', 
                                        marginLeft: 'auto', 
                                        marginRight: 'auto', 
                                        borderRadius: 8 
                                    }}>
                                    {dummyData.storesData.filter((img) => img.store ===  product.store ).map((img) => (
                                        <View style={styles.otherProducts}>
                                            <View style={styles.otherProductsImage}>
                                                <Image 
                                                    style={styles.otherImages} 
                                                    source={{ uri: `${product.image}` }}
                                                    />                                    
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.otherProductsDetails}>
                                                <Image 
                                                    style={styles.otherImagesLogo} 
                                                    source={{ uri: `${img.image}` }}
                                                />
                                                <View>
                                                    <Text style={styles.CheapestName}> {product.name}</Text>
                                                    <Text style={styles.CheapestMeasurement}> {product.measurement} </Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <Text style={styles.CheapestPrice}> ${product.price}</Text>   
                                                <TouchableOpacity 
                                                    style={{backgroundColor: COLORS.primary, padding: 10, borderRadius: 4, width: '92%', marginTop: 10,}}
                                                    onPress={() => {onAdd(product, qty)}}
                                                >
                                                    <Text 
                                                        style={{
                                                            color: '#fff', 
                                                            fontWeight: '600', 
                                                            textAlign: 'center'
                                                        }}>
                                                        ADD TO CART
                                                    </Text>
                                                </TouchableOpacity>                             
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    ))}
                                </View>
                            ))}             
                        </View>
                    : <><Text> No other product available for price comparison </Text>
                    <Text onPress={() => goBack()}> Return to the previous page </Text></> }
                </View>
                <BottomTabs/>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )}
    
    
</SafeAreaView>
)
}

export default PriceComparison

const Icon = (props) => (
 <View>
    <Ionicons 
        name={props.icon} 
        size={25} 
        style={{
            marginBottom: 3,
            alignSelf: 'center'
        }} 
        color={props.color}
    />
</View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
scroller: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }, 

Header: {
    marginTop: 40,
    flexDirection: 'row',  
    marginHorizontal: 5, 
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20        
},

Cheapest: {
    height: '40%',
},

CheapestLogoImage: {
    width: '50%',
    height: '50%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    marginTop: 10
},

CheapestDetails: {
    marginTop: 5,
    height: '100%'
},

ProductImage: {
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    resizeMode: "contain"
},

CheapestDetails: {
    width: '100%',
},

CheapestTitle: {
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10
},

CheapestName: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '600',
    lineHeight: 19
},

CheapestMeasurement: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '500',
    lineHeight: 19,
    color: COLORS.darkGray2       
},


CheapestPrice: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '600',
    lineHeight: 19        
},

CheapestSavings: {
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginRight: 10       
},

SavePrice: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '600',
    lineHeight: 19,
    color: COLORS.primary        
},

SavePercentage: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '600',
    lineHeight: 19,
    color: COLORS.Tomato  
},

otherProducts: {
    flexDirection: 'row',    
},

otherImages: {
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    resizeMode: "contain",
},

otherProductsDetails: {
    marginTop: 20,
    width: '65%',

},

otherImagesLogo: {
    height: '20%',
    width: 120,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 6
    
}
});
```

Comment: which os your testing on ios or android

Comment: both ios and android

Comment: your code provided in question isn't helping helping to solve the problem can you provide reproducible code ,https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the outer view. Add `style={{ flex: 1 }}` to the ScrollView.

Explanation: think of ScrollViews as having two levels - an outer and inner View. The inner View is styled with `contentContainerStyle`. The outer view is styled with `style`. The outer View needs `flex: 1` to allocate space.